# How can I check if a string is followed by another string of a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have tried the following:

```
if "a string" or "a string 2" in comment, any(string in comment for string in list)
```

The comma is supposed to be something like "is followed by"

Comment: Try to give an example. I made a guess in my answer by providing a `comment` example and a `check_list` example, and the objective: "you want to check if 'How' is followed by one of the words in the following list". I hope it is not too far off your original throught, but if it is, please update your question with an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
comment = 'How can I check if a string is followed by another string'
```

And you want to check if 'How' is followed by one of the words in the following list

```
check_list = ['can', 'string', 'followed']
```

Then you can first split `comment` into a list of words

```
comment_words = comment.split(' ')
```

A `list` comes with a method called `index` to tell us where a specific element is, but if it does not exists it will raise a `ValueError`, so I would use it inside a `try` block to catch the error.

```
try:
    idx = comment_words.index('How') #note that it is case-sensitive
    # should return a `0` to `idx`
except:
    idx = None
```

So if 'How' is among the words, `idx` will be a number, otherwise, it will be a `None`. In this case, `idx` is `0`

Now we will check if 'How' is followed by one of the words in `check_list`

```
if (idx is not None) and\
    (idx + 1 < len(comment_words)) and\
    comment_words[idx+1] in check_list:
    print('How is in the comment, and is followed by one of the words in the check list')
```

Note that we have 3 conditions to check, and because they are compared with  `and`, later condition are checked only if the former condition is evaluated to be `True`. In this case, a positive first condition makes sure 'How' is found, a positive second condition makes sure 'How' is not the last word, and a positive third condition tells us that the next word is one of those in the `check_list`.